# HTML Button problem in page builder (Beaver Bilder)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button

so I have a problem: I use Beaver Builder to create my pages. Whenever I use html button with incorporated css in it and hover animation - whenever i activate hover the default button is visible. I have no idea how to fix it help !!!!

[so this is the button and how it should look like when in hover mode:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Zoc.png)

[and this is how it looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K760c.png)

Could you please help me with a solution ?

```css
button {
  color: #2e276d;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

button::before {
  margin-left: auto;
}

button::after,
button::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f44336;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

button:hover::after, button:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button>
  HOVER ME
</button>
```

Comment: You need to show some code that demonstrates the issue. Otherwise we can only sympathize.

Comment: Kindly add ur css code and html in your question so we can help you better

Comment: ok yay there it is :D HTML and CSS

Comment: The code seems to work fine. What's the issue?

Comment: When you look at the photos - first is how it should look on hover - and second is how it looks - whenever you hover over the "default" button comes up the blue backgroud of the button - it shouldn't be there and I don't know how to remove it ?

Comment: De default button is visible. When you hover - how to remove it ? The problem is not with the Code it's with the default settings ? How to remove that ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are targeting the same button in your CSS, that is also targeted somewhere else in your CSS code or via the Beaver builder itself.

If needed, you can add `!important` to your CSS rules. But I wouldn't recommend this, unless it's really needed, because this wil overwrite all the other CSS rules applied elsewhere in your code.

Below an example of how I use the color **RED** with `!important`, and later try to change it with a different color, *which doesnt work*.

```css
button {
  color: red !important; // this will always be applied
}

button {
  color: #2e276d; // This will not be applied, because of the !imporant above
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

button::before {
  margin-left: auto;
}

button::after,
button::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f44336;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

button:hover::after, button:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button>
  HOVER ME
</button>
```

I would suggest to inspect your code, to see where the default rules that are applied come from (and change if possible), before using the !important rule in CSS.

And I recommend using a specific class for the button you want to target and apply the CSS to that class, instead of targeting the button itself, to avoid overwriting the CSS rules globally.

More here: [!important rule CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important)

Comment: Thank you do much, the problem isn't with the code here. There is a default button set somewhere i don't know if it's wordrpess or beaver buider - the one with the blue background you can see on the second photo that is UNDER the HTM/CSS button I've set up. Even when I go into "Customise" in wordpress and set up button (tried changing colour to white) - STILL this blue one pops up under my transparent button... I just don't know where i can change this or edit this. I hope its makes more sense now ? :D